# Matching an expression using ReGex ,Python

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I have many sentences , though i'd create a function that would operate on each sentence individually. so the input is just a string. My main objective is to extract the words that follow prepositions like in `"near blue meadows"` i'd want `blue meadows` to be extracted.
I have all my prepositions in a text file. it works fine but i guess there's a problem in the regex used . here's my code:
import re

```
with open("Input.txt") as f:
    words = "|".join(line.rstrip() for line in f)
    pattern = re.compile('({})\s(\d+\w+|\w+)\s\w+'.format(words))
    text3 = "003 canopy grace appt, classic royale garden, hennur main road, bangalore 43. near hennur police station"
    print(pattern.search(text3).group())
```

This returns :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-be0cdffb436b> in <module>()
      5     pattern = re.compile('({})\s(\d+\w+|\w+)\s\w+'.format(words))
      6     text3 = ""
----> 7     print(pattern.search(text3).group())

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group
```

The main problem is with regex , my expected output is "hennur police" i.e 2 words after near . In my code I have used `({})` to match from the list of preps, `\s` followed by space , `(\d+\w+|\w+)` followed by words like 19th or hennur , `\s\w+` followed by a space and a word. My regex fails to match , hence the `None` error. 
Why is it not working?

**The content of the `Input.txt` file:**

```
['near','nr','opp','opposite','behind','towards','above','off']
```

**Expected output:**

```
hennur police
```

Comment: You need to check what exactly is in `words`.

Comment: Works for me (though you actually should get `near hennur police`), so you'll indeed need to double check `Input.txt` is correct (one word per line).

Comment: input.txt is of the form ['near','off','opposite'...] and so on.. i've edited my question. check it.

Comment: Is the content of file `"['near','nr','opp','opposite','behind','towards','above','off']"` or `['near','nr','opp','opposite','behind','towards','above','off']` ? (surrounded quotes or not)

Comment: input file is without quotes.. and the variable called words has double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file contains Python list literal. Use [`ast.literal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse the literal.

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("['near','nr','opp','opposite','behind','towards','above','off']")
['near', 'nr', 'opp', 'opposite', 'behind', 'towards', 'above', 'off']
```

---

```
import ast
import re

with open("Input.txt") as f:
    words = '|'.join(ast.literal_eval(f.read()))
    pattern = re.compile('(?:{})\s(\d*\w+\s\w+)'.format(words))
    text3 = "003 canopy grace appt, classic royale garden, hennur main road, bangalore 43. near hennur police station"

    # If there could be multiple matches, use `findall` or `finditer`
    #   `findall` returns a list of list if there's capturing group instead of
    #   entire matched string.
    for place in pattern.findall(text3):
        print(place)

    # If you want to get only the first match, use `search`.
    #   You need to use `group(1)` to get only group 1.
    print pattern.search(text3).group(1)
```

output (The first line is printed in `for` loop, the second one come from `search(..).group(1)`):

```
hennur police
hennur police
```

**NOTE** you need to [`re.escape`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) each word if there's any special character in the word that has special meaning in regular expression.